# How to make the DIV full width in a small screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem here with my design layout:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <img class="advertise-two img-responsive col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" src="http://placehold.it/1050x220" alt="" />
    <ul class="menus">
        <li>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
            <a href="#">menu</a>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- /.menus -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 -->
```

Looks like this:
http://postimg.org/image/ffbjrbg8j/

But in a small screen it appears like this: 
http://postimg.org/image/71gbdxq81/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in a `div` with `class="row"` and add `col-xs-12` to your inner `div`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can center `col-lg-10` using `margin:0 auto` (eliminate offset value)

and then add `col-xs-12`,
something like :

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-xs-12" style='margin: 0 auto'>
```

I can't be sure it will work because it also depends on the other markup you have (rows - contatiners - etc.)